# Creating folds for k-fold CV in R using Caret

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I'm trying to make a k-fold CV for several classification methods/hiperparameters using the data available at
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/sonar/sonar.all-data.

This set is made of 208 rows, each with 60 attributes. I'm reading it into a data.frame using the read.table function.

The next step is to split my data into k folds, let's say k = 5. My first attempt was to use

```
test <- createFolds(t, k=5)
```

I had two issues with this. The first one is that the lengths of the folds are not next to each other:

```
       Length Class  Mode   
Fold1 29     -none- numeric <br />
Fold2 14     -none- numeric <br />
Fold3  7     -none- numeric <br />
Fold4  5     -none- numeric <br />
Fold5  5     -none- numeric
```

The other one is that this apparently splitted my data according to the attributes indexes, but I want to split the data itself. I thought that by transposing my data.frame, using:

```
test <- t(myDataNumericValues)
```

But when I call the createFolds function, it gives me something like this:

```
       Length Class  Mode   
Fold1 2496   -none- numeric <br />
Fold2 2496   -none- numeric <br />
Fold3 2495   -none- numeric <br />
Fold4 2496   -none- numeric <br />
Fold5 2497   -none- numeric
```

The length issue was solved, but it's still not splitting my 208 data accordingly.

What I can do? Is the caret package maybe not the most appropriate?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please read `?createFolds` to understand what the function does. It creates the indices that define which data are *held out* the separate folds (see the options to return the converse):

```
  > library(caret)
  > library(mlbench)
  > data(Sonar)
  > 
  > folds <- createFolds(Sonar$Class)
  > str(folds)
  List of 10
   $ Fold01: int [1:21] 25 39 58 63 69 73 80 85 90 95 ...
   $ Fold02: int [1:21] 19 21 42 48 52 66 72 81 88 89 ...
   $ Fold03: int [1:21] 4 5 17 34 35 47 54 68 86 100 ...
   $ Fold04: int [1:21] 2 6 22 29 32 40 60 65 67 92 ...
   $ Fold05: int [1:20] 3 14 36 41 45 75 78 84 94 104 ...
   $ Fold06: int [1:21] 10 11 24 33 43 46 50 55 56 97 ...
   $ Fold07: int [1:21] 1 7 8 20 23 28 31 44 71 76 ...
   $ Fold08: int [1:20] 16 18 26 27 38 57 77 79 91 99 ...
   $ Fold09: int [1:21] 13 15 30 37 49 53 74 83 93 96 ...
   $ Fold10: int [1:21] 9 12 51 59 61 62 64 70 82 87 ...
```

To use these to split the data:

```
   > split_up <- lapply(folds, function(ind, dat) dat[ind,], dat = Sonar)
   > dim(Sonar)
   [1] 208  61
   > unlist(lapply(split_up, nrow))
   Fold01 Fold02 Fold03 Fold04 Fold05 Fold06 Fold07 Fold08 Fold09 Fold10 
       21     21     21     21     20     21     21     20     21     21
```

The function `train` is used in this package to do the actual modeling (you don't usually need to do the splitting yourself. See [this page](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/training.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Max. Now I'm facing another trouble, that I've linked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972854/how-to-implement-a-hold-out-validation-in-r. Hope someone can help me in this as well

Comment: This response is useful, but it is not true that ?createFolds offers the answer. It is never said in the content of ?createFolds that "It creates the indices that define which data are held out the separate folds"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `caret` package, but I used to write a function calculating CV based on decision tree from the `rpart` package. Of course, the function needs motifying in order to suit your purpose.

```
CV <- function(form, x, fold = 10, cp = 0.01) {
  # x is the data
  n <- nrow(x)
  prop <- n%/%fold
  set.seed(7)
  newseq <- rank(runif(n))
  k <- as.factor((newseq - 1)%/%prop + 1)

  y <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(form), " "))[2]
  vec.accuracy <- vector(length = fold)
  for (i in seq(fold)) {
    # It depends on which classification method you use
    fit <- rpart(form, data = x[k != i, ], method = "class")
    fit.prune <- prune(fit, cp = cp)
    fcast <- predict(fit.prune, newdata = x[k == i, ], type = "class")
    cm <- table(x[k == i, y], fcast)
    accuracy <- (cm[1, 1] + cm[2, 2])/sum(cm)
    vec.accuracy[i] <- accuracy
  }
avg.accuracy <- mean(vec.accuracy)
avg.error <- 1 - avg.accuracy
cv <- data.frame(Accuracy = avg.accuracy, Error = avg.error)
return(cv)
```

}