# How to take inversed indexes of dataset in 10 cross validation?

Tags: r, cross-validation, fold

I have a dataset in db which contain a list of rows,
I want to make a ten cross validation with a balanced data.
So I used this function :

`cvIndex <- createFolds(factor(df$BS), folds, returnTrain = T)`

And it return indexes of ten balanced folds for training.

`for i in n seq_along(cvIndex)) {
trainIndex <- cvIndex[[i]]
testIndex <-  ???`

I want to give the testIndex the missing indexes other then the used for the training.

Comment: Suggeted dupe: [Creating folds for k-fold CV in R using Caret](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909197/903061)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using trainControl function from "caret" library for implementation of k-fold cross-validation. For instance, with the following commands you can set 10-fold corss-validation as the train and test method.

control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)

Comment: did it give a balanced dataset ?

Comment: It randomly divides data into 10 folds and by feeding them to the classifiers they return the performance of classifiers and so on. For more information, please visit following link:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/compare-models-and-select-the-best-using-the-caret-r-package/

Comment: No actually it gives you a biased trainset if your data is not balanced, so I should use a function that balance your dataset

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it, and I really recommend to use that function in a balanced 10 cross validation,

`all_index<-c(1:nrow(df))
testIndex<-setdiff(all_index,trainIndex)`

Then you just use

`trainset <- df[trainIndex, ]    # Set the training set
testset <- df[testIndex, ]      # Set the validation set`